# Is $ N(X) $ a sigma-algebra on $ X $?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $ X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ and define the set $$ N(X):=\{B\cap X:\ B\in \mathcal{B}^n\} $$
and $ \mathcal{B}^n $ is the borel-sigma-algebra on $ \mathbb{R}^n $.

I'm not sure if $ N(X) $ is in general a sigma-algebra on $ X $.

At first I want to show $ X\in N(X) $. But how could you do this?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n\in\mathcal B^n$ so that $X=\mathbb R^n\cap X\in N(X)$.

Comment: And how do I show $ A\in N(X) \Rightarrow A^c\in N(X) $? If I take $ A\in N(X) $ then I get $ A=B\cap X $ for $ B\in \mathcal{B}^n $. So I need a propper set $ D\in \mathcal{B}^n $ such that $ A^c=D\cap X $. But I cannot find a prooper one.

Comment: Just let $D=B^c$.

Comment: But how can I get $ A^c=B^c\cap X $ if $ A=B\cap X $? With the last relation I get $ A^c=B^c\cup X^c $. This looks contradictive.

Comment: $B^c\cup X^c$ is the complement of $A$ in $\mathbb R^n$ but that is not what we are looking at. If we want to verify that $N(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ (not on $\mathbb R^n$) then we must prove that $N(X)$ is closed under complementation in $X$. Observe that the complement of $B\cap X$ with respect to $X$ is $B^c\cap X$ (where $B^c$ denotes the complement of $B$ in $\mathbb R^n$). This because the intersection of $B\cap X$ and $B^c\cap X$ is empty and their union is $X$.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $\mathcal B$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ then collection of preimages:$$f^{-1}(\mathcal B):=\{f^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\mathcal B\}$$is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Proving that is straightforward. Note e.g. that by definition $Y\in\mathcal B$ and consequently $X=f^{-1}(Y)\in f^{-1}(\mathcal B)$. I leave the rest to you.

Apply that on the inclusion function $X\to\mathbb R^n$.